# MySQL wrong query while combining tables

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

I'm querying two tables in separate queries. Doing it that way brings the right results in less than a sec, however, if I try to merge them, it takes really long that I even have to kill the query (lots of records). I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

**Desired Output**

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+    
| name   | computers | printers  |  tvs      |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Peter  |  12       |   1       |   5       |
| Josh   |  20       |   4       |           |
| Bob    |  15       |   4       |   9       |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

**Query 1**

```
SELECT
    names.name,
    SUM(IF(pcs.electronic = 'computers', 1,0)) AS computers,
    SUM(IF(pcs.electronic = 'printers', 1,0)) AS printers
FROM
    electronics.pcs LEFT JOIN electronics.orders 
    ON pcs.id = orders.id
    LEFT JOIN electronics.buying
    ON orders.id = buying.id
    LEFT JOIN dbnames.names names
    ON names.clientid = pcs.clientid
WHERE
    pcs.clientid IS NOT NULL AND
    pcs.belongs IN (10)
GROUP BY pcs.clientid
```

**Table 1 - query 1**

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+ 
| name   | computers | printers  | 
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| Peter  |  12       |   1       | 
| Josh   |  20       |   4       |
| Bob    |  15       |   4       |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT
    names.name,
    SUM(IF(tvs.electronic = 'tvs', 1,0)) AS tvs
FROM
    electronics.tvs LEFT JOIN dbnames.names names
    ON names.clientid = tvs.clientid
WHERE
    tvs.belongs IN (10)
GROUP BY tvs.clientid
```

**Table 2 - query 2**

```
+--------+-----------+
| name   |  tvs      |
+--------+-----------+
| Peter  |   5       |
| Bob    |   9       |
+--------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a simple **`UNION`**?

```
SELECT
    names.name,
    SUM(IF(pcs.electronic = 'computers', 1,0)) AS computers,
    SUM(IF(pcs.electronic = 'printers', 1,0)) AS printers
FROM
    electronics.pcs LEFT JOIN electronics.orders 
    ON pcs.id = orders.id
    LEFT JOIN electronics.buying
    ON orders.id = buying.id
    LEFT JOIN dbnames.names names
    ON names.clientid = pcs.clientid
WHERE
    pcs.clientid IS NOT NULL AND
    pcs.belongs IN (10)
GROUP BY pcs.clientid

UNION ALL

SELECT
    names.name,
    SUM(IF(tvs.electronic = 'tvs', 1,0)) AS tvs
FROM
    electronics.tvs LEFT JOIN dbnames.names names
    ON names.clientid = tvs.clientid
WHERE
    tvs.belongs IN (10)
GROUP BY tvs.clientid
```

Just a thought...

Comment: I'm wondering, don't you need an equal # of columns to union all? also that would combine the result-set in terms of records but what I need is the extra column.

Comment: You are correct my apologies, I was thinking along the lines of @cyberkiwi, just came out wrong :). You probably are going to need a type of `FULL JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN`, like he mentioned, not `UNION`.

Comment: thanks anyway. I'm still wondering if FULL JOINS are supported on MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

A full join would work nicely, but since MySQL doesn't support full join.. you can UNION ALL between the two and take the MAX from the corresponding columns.

```
SELECT clientid, name,
    MAX(computers) computers,
    MAX(printers) printers,
    MAX(tvs) tvs
FROM
(
    SELECT
        pcs.clientid,
        names.name,
        SUM(IF(pcs.electronic = 'computers', 1,0)) AS computers,
        SUM(IF(pcs.electronic = 'printers', 1,0)) AS printers,
        NULL
    FROM
        electronics.pcs LEFT JOIN electronics.orders 
        ON pcs.id = orders.id
        LEFT JOIN electronics.buying
        ON orders.id = buying.id
        LEFT JOIN dbnames.names names
        ON names.clientid = pcs.clientid
    WHERE
        pcs.clientid IS NOT NULL AND
        pcs.belongs IN (10)
    GROUP BY pcs.clientid, names.name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        tvs.clientid,
        names.name,
        NULL, NULL,
        SUM(IF(tvs.electronic = 'tvs', 1,0)) AS tvs
    FROM
        electronics.tvs LEFT JOIN dbnames.names names
        ON names.clientid = tvs.clientid
    WHERE
        tvs.belongs IN (10)
    GROUP BY tvs.clientid, names.name
) Q2
GROUP BY clientid, name
```

Comment: Are FULL JOINS supported on MySQL 5?

Comment: Interesting i see you (following the OP) used `SUM(IF({expr},1,0))`, i usually use `COUNT(IF({expr},1,NULL))` I wonder which better? You can also use `SUM({expr})` and skip the `IF`.

Comment: @the scrum meister - sometimes I rephrase the OP's query, sometimes I don't. Here I touched up the GROUP BY/SELECT mismatch and didn't want to change a working SUM-IF.  I normally use SUM(CASE WHEN) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from
(
  ... first query
) as query1
left join
(
  ... second query
) as query2
on query1.name=query2.name;
```